# Why am I not receiving compile errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elm

How do I compile Elm code within Visual Studio Code?

I am currently using Ctrl + F5 to compile my code.
However, I am not sure why I am NOT receiving any compilation errors based on the code I have below:

[image]

I expect an error reflecting "blah" not being defined.

**NOTE:**

I am attempting to learn Elm and VS Code.
Hence, all of this is new to me.

Comment: Your module name should be the same name as your file. Try renaming your module to `HelloWorld` and try again.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up deleting several files within my project directory. I was then able to observe the compilation errors.